# How to change GeoPoint of Overlay in ItemizedOverlay for mapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I created an MapView with ItemizedOverlays. I need to move some Overlay on the mapView. How to realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the overlays you want to change from the collection and add the new GeoPoints Overlay's to MapView